# Installing Ruboto on Mac using Homebrew-ed Sdk

Tags: macos, homebrew, ruboto

I am trying to install the ruboto gem on my MBP retina.  I have previously installed the SDK and NDK on my computer using Homebrew as the install service and have them pathed as such.  However, here is my problem.

When trying to use 'ruboto setup', the system keeps informing me that is cannot find
"Platform SDK android-19".  I have added the path to the platform/android-19 folder in the .bash_profile, however it refuses to see it as such.  Any hints as to how I might correct this or work around this?

Answer (score 0):

"ruboto setup" expects the platform sdks to be installed in a directory parallel to the "android" command:

```
<android-sdk>/tools/android
<android-sdk>/platforms/android-19
```

You need to ensure that your Android SDK installation follows this structure or file an issue in the Ruboto tracker ( https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/issues ) and ask for "ruboto setup" to support Android SDK installation using HomeBrew.

An alternative is to uninstall your Android SDK and let "ruboto setup" install it from scratch.